# A simple Regex issue

Tags: javascript, java, html, regex, web

I am trying to create a regex for the following String-

```
<tr>
        <td colspan=2>
        <p><b>
        CITY Head: 
        <span >
        <span >##CITY##</span>
        <o:p></o:p>
        </span>
        </b>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
```

I want to find the whole TD block having **CITY Head** in it. I could come with the following regex.

```
<td(.*)[\s](.*)[\s]+CITY Head+(.*)[\s](.*)[\s](.*)[\s](.*)[\s](.*)[\s](.*)[\s](.*)[\s]+<\/td>
```

Basically I had to write `(.*)[\s]` for all the lines above and below the **CITY Head**. But this can be different in different cases.

Therefore, I am looking for a general way to combine all the `(.*)[\s]` into something independent of the number of lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: But as bobince says: *"So go on, parse HTML with regex, if you must. It's only broken code, not life and death."*

Comment: Yes, following bobince's advice, one could eventually study tempered greedy tokens. Then, having issues with performance, go on to study unroll the loop technique. And in the end, just realize that a DOM parser was so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\s\S]*?` will match the smallest possible number (`*` = 0 or more, `?` = ungreedy) of whitespace (`\s`) or non-whitespace (`\S`) (ie **any**) characters.

```
<td((?!<\/?td)[\s\S])*?CITY Head[\s\S]*?<\/td>
```

The assertion `(?!<\/?td)` makes sure the section before `CITY Head` doesn't span more than one table cell.

**But** using a regex isn't a reliable way of parsing HTML. In particular, this regex might pull out the wrong result if the HTML contains a syntax error.

Comment: The above regex would take all the all the TDs which are coming before the "CITY Head". The regex has to be designed in a way where only first TD before CITY Head comes in parsing.

Comment: True, should have tested. I've added a negative assertion to fix it. This is why I usually respond to these questions with "You can't parse HTML with regex" ;)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. :-)